# Convert firebase timestamp to php date

Tags: php, laravel, firebase

What is the preferred way to convert firebase timestamp into real date in php?
Currently I am using this date function and passing time stamp to it:

```
<input class="form-control" type="text" value="{{date('m/d/Y H:i:s',$order['createdAt'] )}}"  >
```

But it is not correctly displaying the year.

> 09/19/51697 20:19:46

Comment: You appear to have a timestamp value in milliseconds there, PHP uses seconds. So you’ll need to divide it by 1000.

Comment: Please check the box next to the answer and mark the answer as accepted if the answer is the best solution for your problem.

Answer (score 0):

use `strtotime` before you convert into date.

```
$timestamp = 1569255279586;
$datetimeFormat = 'Y-m-d H:i:s';
// If you must have use time zones
// $date = new \DateTime('now', new \DateTimeZone('Europe/Helsinki'));
$date = new \DateTime();
echo $date->format($datetimeFormat);
```

result

> Output : 2019-12-04 10:03:33

[check example](http://php.net/manual/en/timezones.africa.php)

Other time zones:

- [Africa](http://php.net/manual/en/timezones.africa.php)
- [America](http://php.net/manual/en/timezones.america.php)
- [Antarctica](http://php.net/manual/en/timezones.antarctica.php)
- [Arctic](http://php.net/manual/en/timezones.arctic.php)
- [Asia](http://php.net/manual/en/timezones.asia.php)
- [Atlantic](http://php.net/manual/en/timezones.atlantic.php)
- [Australia](http://php.net/manual/en/timezones.australia.php)
- [Europe](http://php.net/manual/en/timezones.europe.php)
- [Indian](http://php.net/manual/en/timezones.indian.php)
- [Pacific](http://php.net/manual/en/timezones.pacific.php)
- [Others](http://php.net/manual/en/timezones.others.php)

Comment: what is contain `$order['createdAt']`?

Comment: it contains this "1569255279586"

Comment: You lose precision with this conversion (no milliseconds).

Answer (score -1):

Comment from @04FS !!

> You appear to have a timestamp value in milliseconds there, PHP uses
>   seconds. So you’ll need to divide it by 1000.

```
<input class="form-control" type="text" value="{{date('m/d/Y H:i:s',$order['createdAt']/1000 )}}"  >
```